# How do you use Jest on Webpack?

Tags: webpack, jestjs

I took a look the official document [Using with webpack · Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack) , but I don't understand.. where's the Jest part in the example?? It looks a normal webpack config file without a Jest to me.

I also took a look some other tutorials e.g. [Web Component Tutorial => Webpack and Jest](https://riptutorial.com/web-component/example/30849/webpack-and-jest) or [What happened to setupTestFrameworkScriptFile? · Issue #2558 · facebook/jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2558), these articles say adding `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: "<rootDir>/bin/jest.js",`, so basically my setup is like the below:

- ./src/test/sum.test.js

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

- ./webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: mode,
  devtool: (mode === 'development') ? 'inline-source-map' : false,

  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: "<rootDir>/bin/jest.js", // <--- added this
  ..
```

Now running `npx webpack serve`, gets an error:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'setupTestFrameworkScriptFile'. These properties are valid:
```

What am I doing wrong here? Just, how can you integrate a simple set of Jest tasks to Webpack?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official example [Using with webpack](https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack) shows us how to find and transform test files, exclude `node_modules` and some module and files, and handle static assets, CSS Modules, module alias when running the test like webpack when using jest. They give a webpack config example and translate the configs to a jest setup.

Webpack can transform your code using `babel-loader` via `loaders` configuration, jest use [transform](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object) configuration to do the same thing.

Webpack uses `url-loader` and `file-loader` handle static assets. But for testing

> usually, these files aren't particularly useful in tests so we can safely mock them out

So we can use the jestjs `moduleNameMapper` configuration to mock the static assets.

Webpack doesn't have a `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` configuration, it's jest's configuration.

There two npm scripts:

```
"build": "webpack",
"test": "jest"
```

You should build and serve your code using webpack, running the test code using jest. They have their own configurations. It's just that some configurations do the same thing.

Comment: I want to run Jest tests automatically on `build` or `serve`. So you mean Webpack and Jest should be used separately, correct? I'm thinking using a webpack hook e.g. `compiler.hooks.afterEmit` to run the test after build automatically, so this idea is good?

Comment: @丶Limeー来夢丶 Yeah, maybe there is a webpack plugin that can do it. I would not mixin `build` or `serve` with `test`. Keep it simple, you can start another process and run `jest --watch` to run the tests.